# How to have a custom side bar slide from right in your metro app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing a metro app where , I want to have a customized bar slide when the user clicks on something in the screen.

This is what i am talking about :-

```
 --------------
|          |   |
|          |   |  <----
|          |   |
 ---------------
main screen  side
              bar
```

In this side bar i want have some simple  controls like image and text block etc..

1) How can i do this , any help would be appreciated

2) Its  not against metro  principles right ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to leverage a flyout like the settings flyout. You might want to look at [Callisto](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/31/introducing-callisto-a-xaml-toolkit-for-metro-apps.aspx).

You could otherwise include a Xaml element that above all others and toggle it's visibility along with a positioning right on the screen. How to position depends on what root element you're using. For positioning an element in a canvas add `Canvas.Right="0"` to the child element.

Comment: +1 for Callisto - it's a great control library and suits this need perfectly.

Comment: can you guide me on how to achieve this ? , i went to nuget packages and searched for callisto and pressed on for install , then it was included in my project .. , but i was not able to find any flyout control , pls let me know

Comment: You can look at http://depblog.weblogs.us/2012/06/28/comdaybe-flyout-control-in-xaml-through-callisto-for-windows-8/ and https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/Flyout for info

Comment: i have implemented the settingflyout by using  callisto as you had said, i am having an issue  on press of default backbutton present on the flyout the flyout is closed and it opens settingPane , so i dont want to show up settingpane , is there any way i can disable the default backbutton which comes on the flyout / is there any way where i cannot show the settingpane, please let me know thanks in advance.

Comment: I forked callisto on github and create a small hack for disabling the button. It is not premium experience but should show the route: https://github.com/sascha-andres/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Settings/SettingsFlyout.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PopUp**.

have a look at this example,

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49

Comment: Where its all about Settings Flyout, it will fit your scenario too.

Comment: i was trying out the sample but it shows this error :- Error 1 The type or namespace name 'WindowCreatedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you missed Windows.UI.Xaml ?

Comment: i have not changed anything with the sample , i just downloaded it and i have tried to built the solution , it shows that error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20861/discussion-between-tirumudi-and-user1516781)

Comment: Are you using windows 8 upgraded version ?

Comment: i am using windows 8 Release Preview

Comment: I'm not sure, but that could be the problem.

Comment: @user1516781 Do not use a preview for development unless you do not distribute it to someone else (you won't come into the store and sideloading might lead into problems, too)

Comment: @Sascha i didnt get what you are saying , if you dont mind , can you explain a bit more what you specifying

Comment: The Release Preview is a beta version. You shouldn't use a beta after the final version has been released. There might (and probably are) changes that will make your programs not running (in both ways: samples written for the final product will have problems on your computer and vice versa). Do yourself a favor and install the final product. Even though it might take some time, you'll save a lot of time as you can get samples to run and you will be able to distribute apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following helper

[WinRT Flyout Helper](http://codepaste.net/erev2v)

```
public class FlyoutHelper
{
    protected Popup m_Popup = new Popup();
    public Popup Show(Popup popup, FrameworkElement button, double offset = 35d)
    {
        if (popup == null)
            throw new Exception("Popup is not defined");
        m_Popup = popup;
        if (button == null)
            throw new Exception("Button is not defined");
        if (double.IsNaN(offset))
            throw new Exception("Offset is not defined");
        var _Child = popup.Child as FrameworkElement;
        if (_Child == null)
            throw new Exception("Popup.Child is not defined");
        if (double.IsNaN(_Child.Height))
            throw new Exception("Popup.Child.Height is not defined");
        if (double.IsNaN(_Child.Width))
            throw new Exception("Popup.Child.Width is not defined");

        // get position of the button
        var _Page = Window.Current.Content as Page;
        var _Visual = button.TransformToVisual(_Page);
        var _Point = _Visual.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        var _Button = new
        {
            Top = _Point.Y,
            Left = _Point.X,
            Width = button.ActualWidth,
            Height = button.ActualHeight,
        };

        // determine location
        var _TargetTop = (_Button.Top + (_Button.Height / 2)) - 
                         _Child.Height - offset;
        var _TargetLeft = (_Button.Left + (_Button.Width / 2)) - 
                          (_Child.Width / 2);

        if ((_TargetLeft + _Child.Width) > Window.Current.Bounds.Width)
            _TargetLeft = Window.Current.Bounds.Width - _Child.Width - offset;
        if (_TargetLeft < 0)
            _TargetLeft = offset;

        // setup popup
        popup.VerticalOffset = _TargetTop;
        popup.HorizontalOffset = _TargetLeft;

        // add pretty animation(s)
        popup.ChildTransitions = new TransitionCollection 
        { 
            new EntranceThemeTransition 
            { 
                FromHorizontalOffset = 0, 
                FromVerticalOffset = 20 
            }
        };

        // setup
        m_Popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
        m_Popup.IsOpen = true;

        // handle when it closes
        m_Popup.Closed -= popup_Closed;
        m_Popup.Closed += popup_Closed;

        // handle making it close
        Window.Current.Activated -= Current_Activated;
        Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;

        // return
        return m_Popup;
    }

    protected void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_Popup == null)
            return;
        if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
            m_Popup.IsOpen = false;
    }

    protected void popup_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        Window.Current.Activated -= Current_Activated;
        if (m_Popup == null)
            return;
        m_Popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use CharmFlyout.
Here is the sample code
 http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CharmFlyout-A-Metro-Flyout-25fe53b6